# How to populate table with headers with associative array data source? Swift XCode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, nsarray

In my iOS app I have a table a table where I want to display a long list of tasks with 4 categories: open, closed, suspended, expired. So I have created a table with 4 headers and each header has a unique identifier for its cell:

[image]

Following a tutorial, after querying a database my tasks are organized in an object whose class is this:

```
import Foundation
```

class TaskMenuItems:NSObject {

```
var sections:[String] = []
var items:[String:[Task]] = [:]

func addSection(section:String, sectionItems:[Task]) {
    self.sections = self.sections + [section]
    self.items[section] = sectionItems
}

func organize(tasks:[Task]) {

    var open:[Task] = []
    var closed:[Task] = []
    var expired:[Task] = []
    var suspended:[Task] = []

    for task in tasks {
        switch task.stato {
        case "Aperto":
            open.append(task)
            break
        case "Chiuso":
            closed.append(task)
            break
        case "Scaduto":
            expired.append(task)
            break
        case "Sospeso":
            suspended.append(task)
            break
        default:
            break

        }
    }

    self.addSection("Aperti", sectionItems: open)
    self.addSection("Chiusi", sectionItems: closed)
    self.addSection("Scaduti", sectionItems: expired)
    self.addSection("Sospesi", sectionItems: suspended)
}
}
```

so it is an associative array where keys are the state of the task while the values are an array of tasks with that state. This is correctly done... the problm is that I'm not able to write the following method to populate the table:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
}
```

So, here is my Swift class view controller associated to the table:

```
import UIKit
```

class AllTasksViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var allTasks = [Task]()
var taskService = TaskService()
var organizedTasks = TaskMenuItems()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
     self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    if (LoggedUser.isLogged) {
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: true)
        self.taskService.requestAllTasks {
            (response) in
            self.allTasks = self.taskService.loadTasks(response) as! [Task]
            self.organizedTasks.organize(self.allTasks)
            /*println(self.organizedTasks.items["Aperti"]?.count)
            println(self.organizedTasks.items["Chiusi"]?.count)
            println(self.organizedTasks.items["Scaduti"]?.count)
            println(self.organizedTasks.items["Sospesi"]?.count)*/
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


/* Number of sections */
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.organizedTasks.sections.count
}

/* Number of rows for each section */
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch section {
    case 0:
        return self.organizedTasks.items["Aperti"]!.count
    case 1:
        return self.organizedTasks.items["Chiusi"]!.count
    case 2:
        return self.organizedTasks.items["Scaduti"]!.count
    case 3:
        return self.organizedTasks.items["Sospesi"]!.count
    default:
        return -1
    }

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
}
```

Actually I'm getting confused by something trivial I know because I think to indexPath as a String and not as an Int...In fact I am supposed to do:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OpenTask",
              forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell//2 
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.organizedTasks.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

but in my case indexPath.row should be a String... :( Moreover, how can I access the n-th task object of that status in that associative array? something similar

```
self.organizedTasks.items["Aperti"][0]
```

won't work...

Would you please give any hint?

Answer (score 0):

In swift you can use this method to display header

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)
{
 /*   if let view = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        view.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)

        let subview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - 2, width: view.frame.width, height: 2))
        subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        view.addSubview(subview) //according to need
    }*/
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
{
    if(section == 0)
    {
        return " Section 0"// according to need
    }
    else
    {
        return " Section 1"// according to need oR make it generic
    }
}
```

Comment: ehm thanks but my problem is not about displaying headers but about populating the cell with this method:

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {